# What basic primitives my render engine needs to support for drawing OTF fonts?

Tags: fonts, rendering, vector-graphics, text-rendering

I am writing my own render engine for a very specific use case and I need to be able to draw a text. At first, I thought that it would be easier to create my own font file where I would by hand define each character using primitives that my engine supports, but after some time, I thought that maybe it is possible to use a standardized vector fonts format such as OTF.

Currently, I am able to render:

- Point
- Line
- Circle line/Filled Circle
- Triangle

So before jumping into the coding, first I want to know what OTF is made from (*What basic primitives I need to add to my project to render these fonts*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenType spec uses vector formats to describe glyph outlines. There are two different vector formats supported:

- TrueType outlines use quadratic beziers. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/ttch01) for an overview. [Apple's TrueType spec](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM01/Chap1.html) provides more details on the quadratic beziers. TrueType outlines are stored in a ['glyf' table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/glyf).
- Compact Font Format, which is based on PostScript, uses various drawing commands and uses cubic beziers for curves. CFF outlines are stored in a ['CFF '](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cff) or ['CFF2'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cff2) table. In terms of graphic primitives, CFF and CFF2 formats are comparable.

You need to implement scan conversion which determines the pixels that are "on" for a given size.

You also need to process hints. For TrueType, this is like implementing a small Turing machine that interprets op codes and data from the font file and manages a stack to tune the outline before scan conversion.

You may find the [FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/) project useful in understanding what is needed. Or, you can save a lot of time and just use FreeType.